# How to get new edgelists after manipulating graphs

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Is there any way to create a dataframe with data from a network?

For example, if I build a graph from an edgelist

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Col1', 'Col2')
```

and then I manipulate the network a bit (e.g., removing nodes or calculating all the triangles),
and I draw it

```
G1 = nx.triangles(G)
nx.draw(G1, with_labels=True)
```

would it be possible to extract the new data that I am plotting? How?

Comment: There are several ways that you can extract info as a dataframe, I am not sure if those works for your (exact) problem:
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/convert.html?highlight=dataframe#pandas

Comment: thanks adrianop01. I tried with `df = nx.to_pandas_edgelist(G, nodelist=['Col1', 'Col2'])` but it returns an empty dataframe. I am wondering how to include the nodelist. I have thousands of nodes in the network. Would it be possible to get this info?

Comment: to [get node names](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html) you can use ```G.nodes```. Are you extracting the edges for **all nodes** in your updated graph or just the edges for **a subset of nodes** in your graph? You could try removing ```nodelist=['Col1', 'Col2']``` as I am sure no node is called ```'Col1'``` and ```'Col2'```.

Comment: I have not got any error, after removing the nodelist. I am looking for the edges for a subset of nodes, i.e., those ones that are in the updated graph. currently, with no nodelist field, it is returning a bigger number of edges (i.e., edges for all the nodes, included those nodes that are not present in the subgraph)

Comment: What do you mean by **the subgraph**? Do you mean the updated graph ```G1``` after you removed some node in ```G```? Please accept my apologies but could you add the code details showing how you get to ```G1``` from ```G```, thanks!

Comment: I added an example for calculating all the triangles. I think it should work as well (to give just an example). Trying to avoid any confusion that I might have made, I have a graph G with n nodes and x edges. I consider to filter some nodes in G, for example all the triangles, and visualize the new subgraph(s). I would need to create one unique/multiple dataset(s) with the new information (so in this case, all the nodes that are in the network which shows only triangles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `G.subgraph(list_of_node_indices).copy()`. In the case of `nx.triangles`, it will return a dict with node name as the keys. What you can do is to extract keys with zero value (assuming you want to filter all nodes containing at least one triangle).

**Example**

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(4,2)
G.add_edge(4,1)
G.add_edge(5,1)
G.add_edge(6,1)
G.add_edge(6,7)
G.add_edge(7,8)
G1 = G.subgraph([ i[0] for i in nx.triangles(G).items() if not i[1]]).copy()
```

```
nx.draw(G)
```

[image]

```
print(nx.triangles(G))

{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0}
```

```
#only node 6,7,8 is included
print(nx.to_pandas_edgelist(G1))

   source  target
0       6       7
1       7       8
```

Comment: Why `(#node_indices)`? Is that a typo?

Comment: oh I mean list of node indices, thx for the reminder

Comment: I actually meant why the `#`  :)

Comment: I deleted ```#``` to avoid confusion, I just meant the input is a list of node indices